# How to rename maven pom artifactId using IntelliJ refactoring?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ 13 and have a Java project setup with its modules based on maven projects.

There is a maven project that I must rename, so I will have to change it's artifactId property value in the pom file.

If I do this manually, I will then have to find all its occurrences and modify those manually as well (ex: where it is included as a module and where it is used as a dependency).

Since IntelliJ provides many refactoring techniques, I thought refactor->rename on the pom artifactId property would be supported, however it does not seem to be.

I could try and do a find/replace .. but that still makes me do all the work logic (error-prone).

IMO, IntelliJ should be able to detect where the pom is included as a module and which other modules use it as a dependency - anyone know of an automatic way to do this - or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`Replace in Path` (Ctrl+Shift+R by default) action with text to find `<artifactId>OLD-ARTIFACT-ID</artifactId>` and text to replace `<artifactId>NEW-ARTIFACT-ID</artifactId>` will do most of the work automatically with the minimum amount of false positives, especially if you additionally configure the proper file name filter (`pom.xml`, obviously).

In detail, here is the complete sequence of steps to rename the maven-based module (assuming that the name of the module matches the name of the directory where the module is located):

1. Comment out the relevant `<module>OLD-ARTIFACT-ID</module>` lines in parent/aggregator poms, then allow IDEA to re-import the project and allow it to remove excluded modules from the project. It is better to remove leftover .iml files too.
2. Perform search&replace from `<artifactId>OLD-ARTIFACT-ID</artifactId>` to `<artifactId>NEW-ARTIFACT-ID</artifactId>` to rename the module in question and to fix all dependency references to it.
3. Perform search&replace from `<module>OLD-ARTIFACT-ID</module>` to `<module>NEW-ARTIFACT-ID</module>` to fix all aggregation references to it.
4. Rename the module directory.
5. Uncomment the relevant `<module>NEW-ARTIFACT-ID</module>` lines in parent/aggregator POM files, then allow IDEA to re-import the project.

If you feel like IDEA misses some useful functionality you should create a feature request at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/. In this particular case, vote for [IDEA-94223](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-94223), [IDEA-72181](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-72181) and [IDEA-104344](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-104344).

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, I could do so indeed. I would like to add, that for consistency's sake, I will also have to search for `<module>OLD-ARTIFACTID</module>` given that my project follows [best practices](http://blog.sonatype.com/2011/01/maven-tip-project-directories-and-artifact-ids/#.U3sxDvmSxEw) aaannd then i will finally have to rename the directory to NEW-ARTIFACTID.. I guess it is worth a feature request!

Comment: Hey @EngineerDollery, the first thing i tried was the Shift+F6 on everything I could think of ... but that did not modify the pom at all..

Comment: Ok, I've removed my answer too because you're right, it doesn't actually work. Seems to be a bug, because simply having a second title for a module is useless.

Comment: Indeed, I forgot to mention about the need to rename directories and <module> references too. As for renaming the module in the project tree - that action *does something* but the result is even worse then search&replacing. I will update the answer to include the bits about directories and parent poms.

Comment: Thank you @OlegEstekhin, that is more or less how I ended up renaming the module. Unfortunately I cannot up-vote your answer yet - not enough reputation :s

Comment: @mcmoe I upvoted for you, so at least the answer is at 0. No idea why not more upvotes, because these steps actually work.